# Autopopulate by searching multiple columns

Tags: excel, auto-populate

I am trying to find a formula that says look at all of column A - if you see the word "Desktop", add up all the amounts for them from Column B and put it in F1.  Then same for Laptops.

I know that I can manually hold down the 'ctrl' key and click on all dollar amounts for desktops, laptops, etc. but this list grows and I don't want to have to go back to cell F1 and insert the new cells to the formula each time.

The equipment is Column A and the dollar amount is Column B.

```
Switch/Cables $14.00 
Misc          $80.00 
Desktop       $567.00 
Monitor       $150.00 
Desktop       $567.00 
Monitor       $150.00 
Switch/Cables $23.00 
Switch/Cables $7.00 
Switch/Cables $6.00 
Misc          $28.00 
Laptop        $1,015.00 
Desktop       $675.00 
Switch/Cables $84.00 
Switch/Cables $32.00 
Misc          $28.00 
Printer       $29.00 
Misc          $30.00 
Misc          $615.00 
Misc          $46.00 
Switch/Cables $28.00
```

Comment: Is this for Excel or something?

Comment: Yes, sorry - trying to do in Excel

Answer (score 0):

First create a list of the distinct column A values by copying them to a separate sheet then removing duplicates.

In the column to the right of each unique value, enter a SUMIF formula, which will sum the values in column B.